# Is my DM being fair?

Tags: dnd-4e

Me & some friends recently started playing 4e & none of us had played anything like it before. However, recently, the guy who was DM-ing at the time (we're taking turns to see who enjoys it/is good at it) killed two of us in one encounter right after an extended rest.

He said that is was all calculated according to difficulty grids in the DMG, however is a "moderately difficult encounter" supposed to be two level 6 elites against a party of four level 4/5s? And should it have been able to kill us? (I should also note that we accidentally buffed ourselves up somewhat, we used the point buy system but just started all ability scores off at 10 then added 20 on top of those)

We generally think he's a bad DM, having enemies that perfectly counter us isn't fun (three of you are defenders? well how about every enemy in this dungeon has at-will free actions that remove marks...), any time we try to do anything imaginative we are just punished (Can I swing over the pit on this rope? Yes, roll acrobatics, 19? You fall. Take 3D6 damage...), All his quests just seem to be his story that we are simply minor characters in, with little thought put into our enjoyment.

Do other people agree that he sounds bad?

Comment: Is there anything good or enjoyable about games with this GM? If not, with all due respect, why are you still playing?

Comment: Voting to close because you're asking too many things and you have no qualifiers/requirements that lead to what would be a good or bad answer for your question.  Sidebar: Why is the party not the same level? It's hard to gauge balance though since you've admitted that you've gone house-rule/homebrew since stat creation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to give a useful metric, one that works better than "Is this fair?"

What do you want from your games?  Is this person willing and able to give that to you?  If not, they're not the right GM for you.

Some folks like really hard challenges.  Some folks don't.  It's clear at least in your description you want to do creative action stuff - swing from chandeliers, etc. and this GM makes it hard or near impossible.

Make a list of 3-5 things you want as a group.  Make those things happen, or decide if any one of you can't provide it, then those folks wouldn't be good GMs for this group.

You may find out that what some of you want is very different from what the other folks want, and you'll have to decide which way to go, and whether it makes sense to keep playing together longterm or play in different groups doing those different things.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you might be expecting something different from the game than your DM.

First of all, you've changed the rules to overcharge your characters to be more powerful than regular. That means your DM needs to adjust to that. This means slightly harder encounters and more challenging problems to deal with. Your DM might be looking to push you as the player(s) to find the challenge in it to do better.

Secondly, you admit that your party composition is not optimal. It is not the DM's fault to pick the party's classes. If you craft a composition that can deal with anything, then you shouldn't be easily countered with a challenge.

Thirdly, this is conjecture since I cannot tell by your question what you expect from the game, but might it be possible that you expect not to die at all? It's difficult to see a character you've built up literally destroyed before your very eyes. As dramatic as that sounds, that might be exactly how you feel. Have you told your DM this?

Perhaps your DM loves the numbers game and you like the roleplay game. If you are rotating DMs and you know this DM will look to make life hard, take that challenge to make his life hard. Each victory will be just that much sweeter for it and maybe you may find it easier to accept your character's death by being less involved in their backstory and more in their numbers.

And then when you play with another DM you can go back to that heavy roleplaying that you love; the heroic die hards who can take on anything and everything.

Fourthly, and lastly, I hope you are not here just to hear the answer you want to hear which is that you are right and he is wrong. That's wrong in every way. You play the game together. So you should communicate what you expect from the game together.